# How can i convert this script v4 to v5?

Tags: pine-script

no matter how hard I tried, I could not convert this script, which was written as v2, to v5 version. Can you help?

```
nATRPeriod = input(5)
nATRMultip = input(3.5)
xATR = atr(nATRPeriod)
nLoss = nATRMultip * xATR
xATRTrailingStop = iff(close > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close[1] > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), max(nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]), close - nLoss),
                    iff(close < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close[1] < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), min(nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]), close + nLoss), 
                        iff(close > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), close - nLoss, close + nLoss)))
pos =   iff(close[1] < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), 1,
        iff(close[1] > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), -1, nz(pos[1], 0))) 
color = pos == -1 ? red: pos == 1 ? green : blue
```

Answer (score 0):

the syntax between version 2 and version 5 have changed, rewrite the code. changed your `iff` (no longer supported) to `if` or use ternary operator `?` . Use the documentation to help you. alternatively you can update it to version 3 and automatically convert it from the relevant drop-down menu
[Documentation V5](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Operators.html#conditional-operator-and-the-function-iff)